# I want to pass ercrypted text in image(stegonography) and then extract that encrypted text again and then decrypt it

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, steganography

I am getting the wrong output. I would also like to apply a password while doing steganography.

I tried initializing message with some string in front of message

```
#Import the required library
from PIL import Image
import stepic
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, 'This is an IV456')
message = input('Enter Message: ')
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
print(ciphertext)

#Open Image or file in which you want to hide your data
im = Image.open('TajMahal.png')

#Encode some text into your Image file and save it in another file
im1 = stepic.encode(im, ciphertext)
im1.save('TajMahalenc.png', 'PNG')

#Now is the time to check both images and see if there is any visible changes
im1 = Image.open('TajMahalenc.png')


#Decode the image so as to extract the hidden data from the image
im2 = Image.open('TajMahalenc.png')
stegoImage = stepic.decode(im2)
print(stegoImage)
obj2 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, 'This is an IV456')
plaintext=obj2.decrypt(stegoImage)
print(plaintext)
```

I am getting this kind of output

```
Enter Message: fbgfbg
b'\xeb*\xb2\xfe\xa5`'
ë*²þ¥`
b'N/\x8f>3\xdey\x9a\xfc\xe5'
```